# iOS: Load a custom UIView from a nib

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, interface-builder, nib

I want to create my own UI library containing several reusable controls. One very simple one could be a LabeledView that will contain a UIView (most probably an UIImageView) and a UILabel below.

```
----------------
| outer UIView |
| ------------ |
| |          | |
| |  UIView  | |
| |          | |
| ------------ |
| | UILabel  | |
| ------------ |
----------------
```

How can I implement this in Interface Builder and "inject" the inner UIView and UILabel when creating the outer UIView? I have the outer UIView as File's Owner and the inner UIView and the UILabel connected with IBOutlets to properties in my LabeledView. I am now imagining an init function like:

```
[[LabeledView alloc] initWithView:(UIView *)theView andLabel:(UILabel *)theLabel]
```

That method should load the View from the nib with its defined layout and insert `theView` and `theLabel` into it. This couldn't be to hard, no? I don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

If you've defined the views etc in a nib then you can add them at runtime using `loadNibNamed:` described here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html

This returns an array, the first object will be the top level object in the nib - your container view in the example above.

You dont use alloc/init when loading things from a nib, because the nib itself contains a serialised version of the object, which is already instantiated.

Comment: Yes, i got that. But I have the inner UIView and the UILabel before creating the outer UIView from that nib and I want to "inject" those so that they adapt the layout and size of the nib.

Comment: I assumed the inner view and label were part of the nib. You've said they are outlets that are connected to the outer view, which is the file's owner, so they must be part of the nib. I don't understand what you are asking for, can you give me more information?

Comment: I don't want the nib to create the subview and label. I want to use a view and a label that was created before. The view and label in the nib should just act as placeholders I can add the formerly created view and label in so that they inherit the layout and properties from the nib. I came to the conclusion that this is most probably not possible at all and I need to implement the layouting myself...

Comment: In that case, why can't you just have a nib with a placeholder subview and label, defined by outlets, and then once youve loaded it, set the outlet values to your pre-made view and label?

Comment: It should do _something_. Im still not 100% sure what you are expecting to happen. How different is the label you want to "inject" versus the one in the nib? Usually for a reusable component (think one of the standard table view cells) you'd create the object then set the text value, font etc. via code, you wouldn't drop in a whole new view and expect it to fit in. If anything, you add the label as a subview, but this removes the point of having the placeholder in the nib.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, to create independent UIView subclass with their own `IBOutlet`, and methods. Also they will be independent of `File's Owner", means you can use them anywhere in your code.

Follow these steps

- Leave the File's Owner field empty.
- Click on actual view in xib file of your CustomView and set its Custom Class as CustomView (name of your custom view class)
- Add IBOutlet in .h file of your custom view.
- In .xib file of your custom view, click on view and go in `Connection Inspector`. Here you will all your IBOutlets which you define in .h file
- Connect them with their respective view.
- In .m file of your CustomView class, override the init method as follow

  -(CustomView *) init{
              CustomView *result = nil;
              NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options: nil];
              for (id anObject in elements)
              {
                      if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]])
                      {
                              result = anObject;
                              break;
                      }
              }
              return result;
          }
- Now when you want to load your CustomView, use the following line of code [[CustomView alloc] init];